# Adding y-axis to CrossFilter examples

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

[image: How to add the Y-Axis labels?]

I adapted the code from here: http://square.github.io/crossfilter/ to my own data - how do I show the counts on the left on the y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is this:

```
// Create y-axis
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("left")
    .scale(y);

// Add y-axis.
svg.append("svg:g")
    .call(yAxis);
```

`x` is your horizontal [scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales).
`svg` is your visualisation's root [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) element (as a [selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections)).

You might want to consult the [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes) or [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1166403) from [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365814/mbostock).